# Maven assembly plugin cannot find deployed shared assembly

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven assembly that is working just fine inside a project.  I wanted to share this assembly and so moved it to its own project.  If followed the instructions at http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-LATEST/examples/sharing-descriptors.html to install the shared assembly and then use it in multiple projects.

This all works great if I run 'mvn install' on my box.  I can also run 'mvn deploy' and the little assembly shows up in my enterprise repo just fine.

However, if I blow away my local repository, or if someone else tries to build a project that uses the assembly, the assembly plugin claims that it cannot find my shared assembly.  The error is something like:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (my-config) @ retriever ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/foo/assemblies/1.0/assemblies-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.377 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-11T11:55:28-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/481M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (my-config) on project retriever: Execution my-config of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.foo:assemblies:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

My shared assembly is com.foo:assemblies:1.0.  If I run 'mvn install' in the assembly project again locally then the project using the assembly will find it just fine.  But that sort of defeats the purpose of making it a shared assembly if every user needs to checkout and install it.

The log makes me think that the plugin is only looking at my local repo and then maven central.  But it should also be looking in my enterprise repo.  The enterprise repo is set up correctly as far as I can tell because all the non-maven-assembly-plugin dependencies are working just fine.

Has anyone had luck with shared assemblies that are deployed and not just installed?  Is there something I need to do that is special for deploying assemblies?